# How do I get the android icons to change state (highlights)?

Tags: android, icons, android-widget, standard-icons

I am using the Android SDK icon-button for refresh (ic_menu_refresh) in a widget and I need to change the selection state when it is pressed.  How is this done?  Do I define an XML for the button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You define the different states in xml via selector.

Sample (esp. see the state-attributes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_catlocfilter" android:state_pressed="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_catlocfilter_dark" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_catlocfilter" android:state_focused="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_catlocfilter_dark" android:state_focused="true" />

</selector>
```

Comment: Where do you get bg_catlocfilter?  Are they standard icons from android sdk?

Comment: No, that's just an example from my app. You replace it with your icons (i.e. ic_menu_refresh) that you're using. You create one normal and one highlighted one.

Comment: OK.  I think I have it hooked up correctly, but there is no effect.  Does this work in widget (my guess is 'no').

Comment: my question was intended for widget, but I did not make that clear.  I accept your answer for the question I asked, but I need to re-ask as a widget.