# Android: Add outer glow to ImageButton

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

I have been looking at these posts:
[StateList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)
, [Different states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380479/how-do-i-get-the-android-icons-to-change-state-highlights)

What I really want is to add an outer-glow or some way to highlight the button onclick versus making different images for the associated states. Is this possible using colors or themes?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

I found a good solution here, not quite the right answer but a good one none the less:

[standard-android-button-with-a-different-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color)

Answer (score 3):

I think you will be better off making an image for the state rather than trying to use software to render this automatically.  The software solution will most likely be slower.